# Convert JSON to POJO using nested classes

Tags: java, json, jackson, inner-classes

I am receiving some JSON in a String format from a data provider, from my understanding i can convert the JSON into POJO using a class file. The data provider provides `@JsonProperty` classes which i've managed to use to convert the JSON into POJO's. The question i have is, is it possible to have just one nested java class that contains all the `@JsonProperty` classes? Instead of having separate classes, of which there are many.

**Json String:**

```
{
    "BillingAccount": {
        "AccountType": "Trial",
        "AccountBalance": 999.99,
        "TransactionCost": 999.99,
        "ExtraInformation": {}
    },

    "Request": {
        "RequestGuid": "abcde",
        "PackageId": "abcde",
        "PackageVersion": 2,
        "ResponseVersion": 2,
        "DataKeys": {
            "Vrm": "example"
        }
    }
}
```

**BillingAccount.java**

```
public class BillingAccount
{
    @JsonProperty("AccountType")
    public String accountType;
    @JsonProperty("AccountBalance")
    public double accountBalance;
    @JsonProperty("TransactionCost")
    public double transactionCost;
    @JsonProperty("ExtraInformation")
    public ExtraInformation extraInformation;
}
```

**DataKeys.java**

```
public class DataKeys
{
    @JsonProperty("Vrm")
    public String vrm;
}
```

**Request.java**

```
public class Request
{
    @JsonProperty("RequestGuid")
    public String requestGuid;
    @JsonProperty("PackageId")
    public String packageId;
    @JsonProperty("PackageVersion")
    public int packageVersion;
    @JsonProperty("ResponseVersion")
    public int responseVersion;
    @JsonProperty("DataKeys")
    public DataKeys dataKeys;
}
```

**POJO.java**

```
public class POJO {

    @JsonProperty("BillingAccount")
    public JSONSorter.BillingAccount billingAccount;
    @JsonProperty("Request")
    public JSONSorter.Request request;

}
```

**Ideal Solution:**

As you can see there is the JSONSorter class which houses the other classes. So when creating the POJO i would call public `JSONSorter.Request request;` as opposed to calling just Request. Reason this is an ideal solution is because Request class could have different properties depending on what dataset is being retrieved. So instead of having Request1, Request2, Request3 wouldn't it be better to have JSONSorter1, JSONSorter2, JSONSorter3. Each of which would contain the classes necessary to the data being retrieved.

```
public class JSONSorter {

    public class Request {
        @JsonProperty("RequestGuid")
        public String requestGuid;
        @JsonProperty("PackageId")
        public String packageId;
        @JsonProperty("PackageVersion")
        public int packageVersion;
        @JsonProperty("ResponseVersion")
        public int responseVersion;
        @JsonProperty("DataKeys")
        public DataKeys dataKeys;
    }

    public class DataKeys {
        @JsonProperty("Vrm")
        public String vrm;
    }

    public class BillingAccount {
        @JsonProperty("AccountType")
        public String accountType;
        @JsonProperty("AccountBalance")
        public double accountBalance;
        @JsonProperty("TransactionCost")
        public double transactionCost;
        @JsonProperty("ExtraInformation")
        public ExtraInformation extraInformation;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is wrong with this solution? You can skip some properties if you want and use `UPPER_CAMEL_CASE` naming strategy (https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-advanced-annotations) but generally it is the most flexible approach.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with it, however in my case there would be hundreds of classes due to different data sets being retrieved with the same name. So there would be numerous versions of 'public class DataKeys{}' depending on what data is being retrieved. I've updated my post with what an ideal solution would look like. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: If so many different properties is possible according to dataset imho you should go with a dynamic way instead of concrete type classes like `HashMap<String, Object>`

Comment: OR if the only `DataKeys` properties is dynamic and changing then you can consider to use HashMap for just `DataKeys` and the remaining parts stay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ideal solution should work. The only thing that's missing is making the inner classes static. They have to be static so that your JSON deserializer can instantiate them without needing to attach them to an existing instance of JSONSorter.